# Added existing IAM role to EC2 instance using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

I have an existing IAM role setup (not created suing Terraform), i need to add this  to a an EC2 instance I have built using Terraform.

I have tried various options of using the aws_iam_role, iam_instance_profile commands but cannot get this to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your Terraform code where you've tried it and also how that doesn't work for you? If there's an error show the exact error. If it behaves differently to how you'd expect then explain the different between your expectations and what happens.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import your existing role into Terraform.

`terraform import aws_iam_role.my_role_identifier my_existing_role_name`

2. Create an instance profile from this role.

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "my_instance_profile" {
    name = "my_instance_profile"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.my_role_identifier}"
}
```

3. Pass this instance profile to your instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
    ...
    iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.my_instance_profile.name}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. In the end I cloned my role using terraform, assigned it to the instance and removed the original.